# How do i get the values from multiple forms in different pages in node js?

Tags: html, angularjs, node.js, wordpress, frontend

Im really new to node/MEAN stack and i would appreciate if somebody can help or guide me or point me to some related tutorials.

I have just purchased a wordpress template for a booking application. This came with different pages for choosing a date, selecting a room, the booking information and confirmation.

I have put the html pages inside the public directory and it was already running.

From the index, clicking booking will lead me to choose-date.html, then to booking info without touching the server side. **How do I get the value from the date in the choose-date.html and booking-info.html?** I planned to submit the information on the confirmation page.

In asp.net mvc, this could be done by having a controller and action for each and save a session in the server. If i use asp.net mvc, i have to modify the html to use a layout and such. This i want to avoid.

Angular is for single page only and as i understood it could not be applicable to this scenario though im planning to used it to post on the confirmation page.

Any suggestions? I very much appreciate any help and guidance.

Here my folder structure:

[image]

Comment: Hard to make any sense out of this. Wordpress typically runs with php and you are asking about MEAN stack. No idea what you are trying to do

Comment: So you say it is not possible to use wordpress to MEAN?

Comment: No...didn't say that but are 2 different applications in different server side languages. Can use angular inside wordpess but that isn't using The M,E or N in MEAN

Comment: I have my folder structure above. I am going to use mongodb to save the booking. I am not sure if this is the right thing to do.

Comment: So what does wordpress have to do with your plans?

Comment: Everything under the public folder is the "wordpress" template i purchased. I wanted to use that template to create a MEAN app. Use mongo to save the data, Express for routing/api stuff, and angular on the client side under that template. What I sort of asked is, angular is for single page only, but as you can see above, the booking can only be completed using several pages. From choosing a date, to a room, to booking information then post it to the express api/route. How can i collect the values from the previous pages like the date and rooms.

Comment: Not clear what specific problem is then. Suggest reading [ask] and [mcve]

Comment: thank you for the fast reply. How do i collect the values from choose date, then choose room then into the booking information where i will then post the data to the api.

Comment: Same way you do in any angular app. That is far too broad a question

Comment: Angular is, as i have understood, for single page application only, in my case there are 3 pages. Thanks for your time.

Comment: No point in using MEAN if you want to load new pages every step when you can do it all in one page load and use angular routing. Then simply use an angular service to share data across multiple controllers

Answer (score 1):

You have essentially three choices as I see it.  1) write a new app using the Wordpress template as inspiration.  2) write a Wordpress app using the template you provided.  3) write an Express app and use the template you bought for just the html.

If you do the third, there are a lot of options for doing a multi step process, but the basic pattern I've found useful is to just have one object in the database (eg your booking) and have each form be either a PUT request (so you send the whole object over the wire on each form submit) or a PATCH (where you only send the new info).

FWIW you could still do the ASP.NET method you described with storing things in session, I just don't think that's a great way to go regardless of framework.

## edit

I guess arguably you could also use angularjs and treat each html chunk as an angular template that gets fetched as a directive demands it.  But I think that'd be tricky to get right given where you're at with the project.

Comment: Tricky may be the wrong word.  Time consuming perhaps.  we don't know the state of those files and from the OPs comments it looks like he's not strong in Angular so there is a lot he can get frustrated on.

Comment: Agree about strength part. Whole thing sounds like wanting to build an Audi and wanting to mix parts from a Honda and Ford to make it work. Providing various options is a good answer

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time. I am really not strong on angular specially on the UI side of things. I guess i have to learn more about those things. So you think it would be better if i can made those html a single page like this one https://scotch.io/tutorials/single-page-apps-with-angularjs-routing-and-templating?